# Game center and leaderboards

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, game-center

I am looking to implement game center leader boards in my app but have a question:

Since the app has been sold in several countries, I wanted to allow the user to see an "overall" leader board which would show all users from anywhere, and then a "country" leader board which would show just those scores for that that country.

Question is:  Since it appears that leader boards only take the user id and score, would this mean I would need to create a separate for the overall, and then a leader board for each country?  If this is the case, how would I know what countries to create?  Or would I have to just create ones by regions..such as Central America, Europe, etc..

Thanks in advance for any and all help.

Geo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats a very interesting question..

Unless you can detect where the person is from, you basically can only send it to a overall world leaderboard.. as you can control what countries you wan to release your game to, i believe you can create the leaderboards according to the countries.. But by regions would be a a better option..

Yes.. You have to create leaderboards for each region and a overall leaderboard..